# Why time(NULL) saved to file and loaded and just time(NULL) are not the same?

Tags: c++, datetime, console

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ms;
    fstream t;

    t.open( "time.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out );
    t << time(NULL);

    t >> ms;

    cout << endl << " from file: " << ms;
    cout << endl << " from time: " << time(NULL) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I think "from file", and "from time" should be the same (**EDIT:** similar, not the same). Why it isn't?

---

Output:

```
form file: 4273382
from time: 1401823106
```

Comment: What does it show if you replace `t << time(NULL);` with `t << 3;`?

Comment: define `ms` as `time_t`, not `int`

Comment: Please show your outputs in the question as well.

Comment: Time marches on. Aside from that, the way you write and then immediately read from `t` seems fishy, is the "from file" output sensible (i.e. only slightly different from the "from time" one)?

Comment: I think they shouldn't be same. Unless your disk is very, very fast.

Comment: One is that your stream is buffered so the input probably isn't written to disk immediately. Two is that you need to reset the position indicator before performing the subsequent read.

Comment: OK, not the same, but similar.

0x499602D2, how to reset position indicator?

Comment: @Voltinus `t.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg)`

Comment: If I indicate ms with some value (0 for example), in shows "from file: 0". I think the problem is that it don't read the data from the file. But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Your stream was buffered so the data wasn't prepared for reading. So the output your are seeing is the garbage value of `m`. Moreover, the position for reading was altered after writing. Use `t << std::flush` after writing to flush the data and `t.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg)` before reading to reset the position.

---

The problem is that you're outputting to the stream and assuming the input has been written immediately when that is not the case. Streams are buffered by default and will flush their buffers under certain conditions (one of them being when an explicit call to `flush()` is made or when their buffer runs out of room). Since this is a simple example, buffering as an efficiency measure is negligible. You can safely turn off buffering using `pubsetbuf()`:

```c++
t.open( "time.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out );
t.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(nullptr, 0);
```

These are the only arguments with which you can call `pubsetbuf()` and have well-defined behavior. This will disable buffering for the stream so that the subsequent output operation will send the data directly to the file. Alternatively, you can call `t.flush()` or do `t << std::flush` which will simply flush the stream on demand.

The next problem is that you are reading from a stream *directly* after writing to it, which is wrong. Bidrectional file streams share a joint buffer and are defined to have synchronized position indicators. When an output operation moves the *put* pointers, so too do the *get* pointers. One has to reset the pointers to the beginning when reading back the data into the program. You can do this using either `seekg()` or `seekp()`. Either one will do because the pointers are synchronized:

```c++
t << std::time(nullptr);
t.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
t >> ms;
```

Also, don't forget to check if your input succeeded. If it did not succeed you could suffer from the effects of Undefined Behavior by using an uninitialized variable.

---

Program:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::time_t ms;
    fstream t("time.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
    t.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(nullptr, 0);

    t << std::time(nullptr);
    t.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    if (t >> ms)
    {
        std::cout << " from file: " << ms << std::endl;
        std::cout << " from time: " << std::time(nullptr) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: "time_t is not member of std" and "nullptr was not declared in this scope", but after correct, it works. Many thanks!

Comment: @Voltinus, it is if you include `<ctime>` instead of `<time.h>`

Comment: To be complete, point out that `ms` is only showing its original uninitialised non-value.